# Return values from one pandas data frame column that match a repeating index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like so:

```
index.   columnA.   columnB.   columnC.   
  1.      data.       data.      data. 
  2.      data.       data.      data. 
  3.      data.       data.      data. 
  4.      data.       data.      data.   
  1.      data.       data.      data. 
  2.      data.       data.      data. 
  3.      data.       data.      data. 
  4.      data.       data.      data.   
  1.      data.       data.      data. 
  2.      data.       data.      data. 
  3.      data.       data.      data. 
  4.      data.       data.      data.   
  1.      data.       data.      data. 
  2.      data.       data.      data. 
  3.      data.       data.      data. 
  4.      data.       data.      data.
```

How can I return (from `columnA`), those datum points which also are in index `3.`?

Comment: Use `df.loc[3., 'columnA']`

Comment: @jezrael,thank you. Could you put it in an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[3., 'columnA.']
print (df)
index.
3.0    data.
3.0    data.
3.0    data.
3.0    data.
Name: columnA., dtype: object
```